# how to make a array copie for calculations in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm busy to make a html(canvas) version of "Conway's Game of life" (just for fun and learning) and i'm stuck at the point were i have to calculate the next generation.

The problem that i have is that i need a backup version from the old gen to make the new one and sinds im using a "2D" array for my drawing i tryed something like:

```
var game = []; //this is the original array in 2D
var calc = game.slice();
// here the code to edit "game" and draw using "game"
// here the code to calculate the next gen on "calc" using the info from "game"
game = calc.slice();
// draw using info on "game"
```

but somehow this didn't work on me...

So is there a mistake that i make or do i have to use another solution for this?

Also i did find some info on ".slice" on here but or i need more info on this or i'm stupid...

Greetings...

Comment: When you say, "It doesn't work" what exactly are you getting and what did you expect to get?

Comment: @RobAnthony what i think is going wrong is that if i change "calc" that "game" is also (automaticly) changed what i don't want until i say so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a deep copy (multidimension) then you should go through each layer at a time and slice it.

```
var calc = game.map(function(x){
    return x.slice();
});
```

If you plan on doing this more than once then just create a function for it:

```
function deepCopyArray(arr){
    return returnArray = arr.map(function(x){
        return x.slice();
    });
}

var calc = deepCopyArray(game);
```

If you don't want to use map then you can also do it with just a for-loop:

```
var calc = [];

for(var i = 0; i < game.length; i++){
    calc[i] = game[i].slice();
}
```